# SQL Server DB Property Issue

Tags: sql-server, ssms

After SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU3) patching we are not able to open the user database properties. Whenever its opened am getting below error:

> Method not found: System.collections.specialized.stringCollection
>   Microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.getpropertynames(System.type)'.
>   (SqlManagerUI)

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but since I've seen a number of scenarios where this has fixed odd errors in SSMS 2016, close SSMS, clear out all temporary files using the [Disk Cleanup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026616/windows-disk-cleanup-in-windows-10) utility (cleanmgr.exe), start up SSMS, and then try this operation again.

Worst case you're no better off than you are now, but you've got a little more free disk space.